# How to create multiple jwplayer playing buttons

Tags: audio, joomla, joomla3.0, jwplayer, audio-streaming

This is a jwplayer case. I have a website with music album pages. Right now I have a jwplayer playing a playlist and works fine, but I want to have a table listing all the songs by track number and a play icon that plays the song on the first  of each line. So far I managed to create a play icon that plays the full playlist but no luck on how to create as many icons as the number of songs and that each plays a different song from the playlist.

This is a representation of what I want to do

---

play icon (song 1) | track number | title song 1 | duration

play icon (song 2) | track number | title song 2 | duration

---

The current code I have is this, which creates a single play icon that plays the playlist. This code, by the way is pretty awesome as it plays next song automatically and controls the pause/play of the main player. This website runs on joomla.

```
<script>
   var playerInstance = jwplayer('container');
    playerInstance.setup({
    playlist: [{
//DYNAMICALLY GENERATED PLAYLIST
        <?php
            $album_id = $this->item->id;
// Get default database object
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
// Get a new JDatabaseQuery object
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query = 'SELECT position, name, length, filename FROM XXX WHERE `album_id` = ' . $db->quote( (int) $album_id ) . ' ORDER BY `num` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30';
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $results = $db -> loadAssocList();
            foreach($results as $row){
            echo "file: \"/". htmlentities($row['filename']). "\", ";
            echo "title: \"". htmlentities($row['name']). "\"";
            echo "},{";
            }
        ?>  }]
//END DYNAMICALLY GENERATED PLAYLIST
    controls: false
                        });
    playerInstance.on('play', function()    {
    document.getElementById("videoPlayPause").style.backgroundPosition = "-263px -70px";
                                            });
    playerInstance.on('pause', function()   {
    document.getElementById("videoPlayPause").style.backgroundPosition = "-287px -70px";
                                            });
</script>

<br/>

<div class="videoPlayerControls playing" id="videoPlayerControls">
<button id="videoPlayPause" onclick="playerInstance.play();" onmouseout="if(playerInstance.getState() == &quot;IDLE&quot; || playerInstance.getState() == &quot;PAUSED&quot;){document.getElementById(&quot;videoPlayPause&quot;).style.backgroundPosition = &quot;-62px 0&quot;;} if(playerInstance.getState() == &quot;PLAYING&quot;){document.getElementById(&quot;videoPlayPause&quot;).style.backgroundPosition = &quot;-62px -50px&quot;;}" onmouseover="if(playerInstance.getState() == &quot;PLAYING&quot;){document.getElementById(&quot;videoPlayPause&quot;).style.backgroundPosition = &quot;-263px -70px&quot;;}if(playerInstance.getState() == &quot;IDLE&quot; || playerInstance.getState() == &quot;PAUSED&quot;){document.getElementById(&quot;videoPlayPause&quot;).style.backgroundPosition = &quot;-287px -70px&quot;;}" type="button">Play/Pause</button>
```

Anyone has done something like this?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you just need to load the URL of the file you want to play into the player, like this.

```
<script>
    jwplayer('yourPlayerDivId').setup({
        file: 'track1.mp4'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a loaded playlist, you can access (play) any item in the playlist directly using the **playerInstance.playlistItem(*index*)** method.

This starts playback of the playlist item at the specified *index* - bearing in mind that the first item in the playlist would have an index of 0.

You should therefore be able to attach a click event to each corresponding 'Play Icon' which calls this method with an incremented *index* in order to access the associated playlist item.

BTW: Since JW7 the **playerInstance.getState()** reports the state as a lowercase string...